# Using "GO" in a SSDT post-deployment script

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-data-tools

My SQL Server 2008 R2 database gets deployed from a SSDT project I created.  One strange requirement in this case is to change one of the primary key columns to or from `IDENTITY` depending on where it's deployed. I'm not wild about the requirement but that's not my question.

What I have done is set up a post-deployment script that should run conditionally, depending on where the deployment is occurring. So far, so good.

In my script I am doing an `ALTER TABLE ADD` command to set up a new column, populate it and rename it to the old column. After this I try to do an `UPDATE` to the new column and it glitches because the column doesn't exist. I put a `GO` statement right under the `ALTER TABLE ADD` command and when I test-run the script in isolation, this solves the problem, everything works great.

```
-- Add a clone of the ID column with no Identity constraint
ALTER TABLE Communication ADD CommunicationIdNoIdentity INT NOT NULL;
GO
UPDATE Communication
SET CommunicationIdNoIdentity = CommunicationID;
```

However it appears this is not legal in the context of a post-deployment script. With the `GO` in place I get a build error right there:

> Error: SQL72007: The syntax check failed 'Unexpected end of file occurred.' in the batch near

How can I get around this? The `BuildAction` on the file is set to "None" which I think is correct.

**UPDATE:** Although the error is emanating from the child script, I finally got it back to the parent.  If I do this:

```
IF @IsDeploymentToDatacenter = 'TRUE'
    :r .\FixIdColumnInCommunicationTable.SQL
```

it works.  If I do this (what I had originally), it fails with the errors I described, among others:

```
IF @IsDeploymentToDatacenter = 'TRUE'
BEGIN
    :r .\FixIdColumnInCommunicationTable.SQL
END
```

Comment: `GO` is **not** a SQL statement or command - it's a **delimiter** used by SQL Server **Management Studio** and thus is not valid in a regular, generic SQL script

Comment: Are you running the file using sqlcmd syntax from a primary post-deployment script?  If not the BuildAction should be PostDeploy.

Comment: @marc_s that's fine, so how can I make the ALTER execute so that when the UPDATE runs, the column is there?  Without delimiting it with GO.

Comment: @db_brad, I have the main PostDeploy.sql running it with a ":r .\FixCommunication.sql" line

Comment: You should be able to do what you are doing here.  I was able to call different commands in the "child" script (script called using sql cmd syntax) separated by GOs and it worked fine. Perhaps try putting your 2 statements in 2 separate scripts and call them both from the main post deploy script using SQLCMD statements.

Comment: I have added an update.  I got it working, though I still don't know why, really.  It seems like it has something to do with putting it inside a BEGIN...END block.  It does not like this.  I can pull it out and it works.  It's not ideal since I can only do it with a single line, unless I reverse the condition and do a RETURN, but that seems like a hack.  Anyone understand what's going on, here?

Comment: Another weird thing is that if the above is set to TRUE, it runs.  If it is set to FALSE (i.e. the script should not run), then I get errors from the child script.

Comment: So something I've learned in all this is that the ":r" command in SQLCMD is really more of a macro.  That is, the file you "run" actually gets literally expanded into the parent script.  So if you put a "GO" in there that should be fine, but if you surround the :r call with, say, BEGIN...END, it would glitch because the "GO" cuts off the BEGIN.

Answer (score 0):

I would be tempted to handle it a different way, you could have the identity in the project but use a deployment contributor to stop it being deployed in the environments you don't need it.

You should be able to use my generic one or write one yourself:

Comment: I'm open to this.  I figured my options were put it in the table script, then remove it in a post-deploy (this is the approach I chose); or don't put it in the table script and then ADD it in a post-deploy.  If I put it into the table script as you suggest, how would I then "stop" it from being deployed?

Comment: Hi Mike - I have double checked and you can't name an identity so using a deployment contributor wouldn't work in this case. I have got around problems like this before by wrapping each of the two scripts in separate sp_execute_sql calls - it isn't very pretty but means they get evaluated and executed in two steps (you can probably get away with just putting the second part in an sp_execute_sql call)